# Gmail Contextual Gadget Not Visible in Gmail

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am trying to develop one gmail gadget. I have prepared my gadget.xml file after reading all the required peoint mentioned in the google documents. But after that they ask to make a manifest file. But as far I have searched, now we don't need to prepare any manifest file. Now, we can prepare it through **Google Apps Marketplace SDK**. I have prepared a manifest here and saved it and enabled it from **console.developers.google.com**.

But after that also, I am not able to see my gadget in Gmail. Please any experienced developer help me in this problem. I trying to solve this problem from long time.

Here is my gadget.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs author="Company Name" height="500" author_email="abc@example.com" author_location="India">
<Require feature="dynamic-height"/>
<Require feature="views" />
<Require feature="google.contentmatch">
<Param name="extractors">google.com:MessageIDExtractor</Param>
<Param name="extractors">google.com:SenderEmailExtractor</Param>
</Require>
</ModulePrefs>
<Content type="html" view="card">
<![CDATA[
<p> Pragmatic Odoo Gmail Integration</p>
<script>console.log('Hello from gadget.')</script>
]]>
</Content>
</Module>
```

Here is my Google Apps Marketplace SDK settings for gadget:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHaWn.png)

Comment: You may want to check the documentations which I have provided in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805631/gmail-contaxtual-gadget-is-now-showing-in-gmail-message) and see if it helps. Also, it will be much easier to address your concern if you also share what you already have done.

Comment: @Teyam I have created a simple gadget spec file in which firstly I am just trying to write Hello. And then I have created manifest by **Google Apps Marketplace SDK**. After that I have submitted it and cleared the gmail gadget cache. But after that also I am not able to see my gadget in any email.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to below hints:

- Add an app to [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) and link it to your Google project, which you describe contextual gadget, with project ID.Here's a sample of web store manifest.json:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sample App",
  "short_name": "Dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "Sample app",
  "app" : {
    "launch" : {
      "web_url" : "http://yourcompany.com"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/128x128-icon.png",
    "16": "icons/16x16-icon.png"
  },
 "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
 "api_console_project_id": "your-project-id"
}
```

- After publish this app, add it to test Google Domain. Since your gadget is in development stage so, don’t publish your app to Public. There are different ["Visibility options"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ale.png) that you can choose.
- To disable cache use nogadgetcache=1 (e.g. https://mail.google.com/?nogadgetcache=1)
- Login with admin account which you want to test it, otherwise take more time to update manifest.
- After Modify “Google Apps Marketplace SDK” click on “Test Installation Flow” to be sure there is no new permission.

**I did these part and works for me:**

- Define google.com:MessageIDExtractor as first extension, however you don’t need that.

> I recommend that select every scopes which you want to use in other
>   extensions here! I don’t know why put it seems the google just ask
>   these permission for my gadget

2. Define Param extractor in gadget.xml separately not with comma:

```html
<Require feature="google.contentmatch">
  <Param name="extractors">
    google.com:MessageIDExtractor
  </Param>
  <Param name="extractors">
    google.com:SenderEmailExtractor
  </Param>
</Require>
```

Comment: Do we need to upload manifest file somewhere or we need to create it?Because I didn't find any place to upload it. I have read one article in which it was written that, we have to create manifest through "Google Apps Marketplace SDK" configuration page.

Comment: I could not find it also, I asked them but there is no answer; it seems deprecated. 
Anyway, I created my manifest with “Google Apps Marketplace SDK”. Until now I pre-canner Google extractor works for me, but I have problem with custom extractor. Here’s my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874194/getting-the-sender-name-in-gmail-contextual-gadget)

Comment: Can we continue the conversation on chat? I want to know the steps to show a gadget in emails.

Comment: I will create an atricle to do that and on that time I'll share it with you.Do you got the answer of your above question?

Comment: Not till now. Please let me know as soon as possible. Will be waiting for your article.

Comment: I'm waiting for an answer of  [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874194/getting-the-sender-name-in-gmail-contextual-gadget)

Comment: I didn't get answer.

Comment: your question didn't helped me. I am not able to see my gadget in Gmail. If you want I can share my specification file and SDK settings. Please let me know if you can help?

Comment: Of courece put it in your question, you don't need to ask! I'll see.What do you mean your specification , do you mean manifiest file at [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard).Anyway there are three part: gadget.xml, “Google Apps Marketplace SDK” and chrome web store app

Comment: Not manifest file. I was telling about gadget.xml file. And since my gadget is in development stage so, I have not used Chrome Web Store.

Comment: First of all, this manifest is different from [Gadget manifest] (https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets?hl=en_GB). If someone wants to add your gadget to bottom GMail, she/he should add you chrome app to her/his account or Google domain. This is reason that you need create an app on [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) and link it to your Google project, which you describe contextual gadget, with project ID. So when you add your chrome app and publish it to chrome store, don’t forget to add your app into test Google account.

Comment: For development stage, there are different [Visibility options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ale.png).

Comment: Is this manifest file is same as gadget manifest or its different? If different, how to prepare this manifest file?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned there are different.

Comment: Check these links to [Manifest File Format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest),  [How to Publish](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish), [Install App](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1053346?hl=en). Here's a sample [GitHube chrome app sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples).

Comment: XQZ , For sample I made a mistake, [check this one](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/web-store)

Comment: Can you share your manifest file which need to be uploaded in app store. I don't have any idea to create it

Comment: {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sample App",
  "short_name": "Dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "Sample app",
  "app" : {
    "launch" : {
      "web_url" : "http://yourcompany.com"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/128x128-icon.png",
    "16": "icons/16x16-icon.png"
  },
 "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
 "api_console_project_id": "your-project-id"
}

Comment: How's going @GauravAgrawal ? Do you get your answer, finally?