# Getting the sender name in gmail contextual gadget

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I’m developing a gmail contextual gadget to get name and email of sender’s email, but I have problem to get name of sender.I tried different ways:

**[1.Using Custom Extractor](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#writing_the_manifest)**

It seems obsoleted and I can not find where I can upload my manifest.xml with custom extractor at “Google Apps Marketplace SDK”. Any Idea!!??

**[2. Using pre-canned extractors](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets?hl=en_GB#using_pre-canned_extractors)**

I defined google.com:SenderEmailExtractor and select “Mail-Sender Address and Mail-Sender Name” scope.Unforthunatly,  I just get sender’s email in google.contentmatch.getContentMatches() but there is nothing related to sender’s name! What am I missing?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="DEV"
    description="Gmail Gadget v2.0"
    height="50"
    author=""
    author_email=""
    author_location="Canada">

      <!-- This one is not specific to Gmail contextual gadgets. -->
    <Require feature="dynamic-height"/>
    <Require feature="views" />

    <Require feature="google.contentmatch">
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:MessageIDExtractor
      </Param>
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:SenderEmailExtractor
      </Param>
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:RawSubjectExtractor
      </Param>
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:EmailTimeExtractor
      </Param>
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:EmailAddressExtractor
      </Param>
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:RecipientEmailExtractor
      </Param>
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:RecipientToEmailExtractor
      </Param>
    </Require>
  </ModulePrefs>

  <!-- Define the content type and display location. The settings
   "html" and "card" are required for all Gmail contextual gadgets. -->
  <Content type="html" view="card">
    <![CDATA[ 
           
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,900,900italic,700italic"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
      
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
      
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
        
        function getSenderName() {
    
            var matches = google.contentmatch.getContentMatches();
            console.log("matches>>", JSON.stringify(matches));
            try {
                for (var match in matches)
                    for (var key in matches[match])
                        if (key == "sender_name") return matches[match][key];
            }
            catch (ex) {
                console.error("getSenderName failed >>", ex);
            }
            return "no found";
        }

        function init(){
          $("#content").text(getSenderName());
        }
        //gadgets.window.adjustHeight(50);
 
        $(document).ready(function () {
              console.log("Gmail Gadget Initializing ...");
              gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(init);
              console.log("Gmail Gadget Initialized.");
          });
          
      </script>
      
      Hello  <span id="content"></span>
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

Comment: here's my google app market SDK manifest: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju97O.png)