# Can we develop Google Contextual Gadget?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am trying to develop a contextual gadget, but not getting any documentation for it. Google provides a document which is very old and not updated from long time. Process explained in that documentation to develop a gadget is deprecated.

Please if anyone have solution, help me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check full documentation in [Gmail Contextual Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets) which was last updated June 29, 2016.

To develop a Gmail Contextual Gadgets, you may want to first check the given implementation parts also discussed in the documentation. Then, you may go through these summary of steps:

> - Use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), or write JavaScript that conforms to [ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/).
>
> **Note:** You need to be using the correct development frameworks to provide an extra layer of protection between your gadget's potential vulnerabilities and your end users. To find out why, see [Using the right frameworks for security](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#using_the_right_frameworks_for_security).
>
> 1. [Choose one or more pre-canned extractors](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#using_pre-canned_extractors). This determines which type of content will trigger your gadget.
> 2. [Write a manifest](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#writing_the_manifest) for the gadget.
> 3. [Write the gadget spec](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#writing_the_gadget_spec). This determines what the gadget will do when it is triggered.
> 4. Publish the gadget spec to a location which is accessible on the **public Internet**. An intranet will **not** work. Your hard drive will **not** work. (Why? Google's servers need to download the gadget. If they can't reach it, then Gmail can't display it.)
> 5. [Install the gadget](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#installing_and_testing_the_gadget).
> 6. Test the gadget by sending yourself some email. The gadget should appear in Gmail whenever you read an email that contains the right sort of content. For more tips on testing gadgets, see [Publishing Your Gadget](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/publish.html) in the gadgets API site.

It will really help if you go through the documentation as there are best practices, limitations and important details that you should note.

This related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805631/gmail-contaxtual-gadget-is-now-showing-in-gmail-message) might also help.

Comment: Do you really think that this documentation is latest? Because I didn't find any way to upload manifest. Google has removed the provision to upload manifest and in place of that we need to create a manifest through **Google marketplace SDK**. Please let me know if we can still upload our manifest.

Comment: I love the "Deploy Application" step, as if there was a button somewhere called deploy application.